# Unable to set cookie with Laravel Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, lumen

According to the [documentation](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/requests#cookies), I am trying to create a simple cookie, but this don't work.

I create it by using the following code :

```
$response = new Illuminate\Http\Response('Hello World');
$response->withCookie(cookie('name', 'value', 43920)); // 43920 = 1 month
```

When I'm trying to see it in the view, I get this error message :

```
 Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Http\Response' not found in [...]\app\Http\Controllers\nameController.php
```

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$response = new \Illuminate\Http\Response('Hello World');
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

$response = new Response('Hello World');
```

Read more about namespaces basic usage: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: What beast mistake ! I had set `use Illuminate\Http\Response;` but after I added `$response = new Illuminate\Http\Response('value');`. This works perfectly. Thank you for your help

Comment: I have another question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556227/why-cookie-isnt-set-in-laravel-lumen

Comment: @zlen I see, will try to reproduce in my Lumen sandbox