# Why cookie isn't set in Laravel Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, lumen

This question is the following of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545555/unable-to-set-cookie-with-laravel-lumen).

I have a message in my view who says : `This site uses cookie [...] Close`.

When user click on `Close`, an ajax request is send to the controller. The function is the following :

```
public function acceptCookie(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->valid == 'accept') {
        $response = new Response('acceptCookie');
        if ($response->withCookie(cookie('acceptCookie', 'accepte', 44000))) {
            return Response()->json(array('statut' => 'Succes'));    
        } else {
            return Response()->json(array('statut' => 'Erreur'));
        }            
    } else {
        return Response()->json(array('statut' => 'Erreur'));
    }
}
```

I haven't any error and JSON returns always `{"statut":"Succes"}`

**Why the cookie isn't set ?**

Comment: Have you tried `$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('name', 'value'));` ?

Comment: Any ideas ? Still stuck same problem

Comment: Did you enable the Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class, in app.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Lumen documentation, it appears as though you need to queue the cookie for a response such as the one in your example. Here's what the docs say:

> Queueing A Cookie For The Next Response
>
> If you would like to set a cookie before a response has been created,
>   use the Cookie::queue() method. The cookie will automatically be
>   attached to the final response from your application.
>
> Cookie::queue($name, $value, $minutes);

My suggestion would be to try replacing the withCookie with queuing the cookie instead. But, you might need to rewrite the function a bit in order to accomodate because it appears as though you're trying to send to responses from one request.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: zien: I also wanted to say that I have in some cases ended up just using PHP's setcookie and $_COOKIE instead of trying to use Lumen's stuff. When all else fails, it's still PHP. :)

Comment: Come back on this question because this isn't solved. I need it. PHP Cookie is not seen by Lumen (e.g. `var_dump($_COOKIE)`). **How to set a cookie with Lumen**? Why is it so difficult ?

Comment: You should still have access to $_COOKIE no matter what. If no cookies are set you should see an empty array with the var_dump($_COOKIE). ... What output to you get from the var_dump?

Comment: It is very very strange. The route page on which I define the cookie returns me all the time that cookie. However, in the others views, `var_dump($_COOKIE)` generates an error `undefined ...`. In Chrome, I have the plugin [cookieManager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-manager/kbnfbcpkiaganjpcanopcgeoehkleeck) who sees the cookie yet ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on `Illuminate\Http\ResponseTrait` line `28`, the `Illuminate\Http\Response::withCookie` method returning `$this`.

```
/**
 * Add a cookie to the response.
 *
 * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie  $cookie
 * @return $this
 */
public function withCookie(Cookie $cookie)
{
    $this->headers->setCookie($cookie);

    return $this;
}
```

Means you have logic failure in your code.

```
// This always return Illuminate\Http\Response instance,
// thus it will never reach ELSE statement forever.
if ($response->withCookie(cookie('acceptCookie', 'accepte', 44000))) {
     return Response()->json(array('statut' => 'Succes'));    
} else {
    return Response()->json(array('statut' => 'Erreur'));
}
```